# Own split method JavaScript

Tags: javascript, string, split

Does a string exist where the result of these two functions would be different?

I'm especially talking about special characters, since the input string could have any valid unicode character in it.

```js
let str = "foo, bar\n";

function method1 (s) {
  let parts = [""];

  for (let i = 0; i < s.length; ++i) // for each character
    if (s[i] === ',') parts.push(''); // the character is our seperator => new start
    else parts[parts.length - 1] = parts[parts.length - 1] + s[i]; // else just add it

  return parts;
}

function method2 (s) {
  return s.split(","); // simply the build in split method
}
  
console.log(method1(str), method2(str));
```

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: You could use `parts[parts.length - 1] += s[i]` instead of `parts[parts.length - 1] = parts[parts.length - 1] + s[i]`

Comment: you might want to add a type check, input like `[]` will get different results

Comment: Sounds like you're actually asking if it's possible to have a JavaScript string where an element of the string is not a character.  No, they can't.  From [ECMAScript® 2015 Language Specification](https://262.ecma-international.org/6.0/#sec-ecmascript-language-types-string-type): "The String type is the set of all ordered sequences of zero or more 16-bit unsigned integer values (“elements”) up to a maximum length of 253-1 elements."

Comment: @Spectric The first sentence

Comment: @lastr2d2 I'm using typescript so I would never pass anything else than a string to this function